# Check if process indirectly resulted in an error

Tags: c#, sql-server, process, cmd

I have the following code that I'm using to open cmd and run the SQL Server setup.exe with a configuration file.

```
            ProcessStartInfo pStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            pStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            pStartInfo.Arguments = "/c /q setup.exe /c /q /configurationFile=../configurationFile.ini";
            pStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = installDir + @"\SQL Server Unpacked";
            pStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            pStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            pStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            pStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = pStartInfo;

            lb_SQLServerReadout.Text = "Please wait while the setup runs";
            p.Start();
```

This is working alright. It'll attempt to install with the details of the configuration file, and if the configuration file contains invalid details then the setup.exe will give an error and not install.

I want to be able to get that error code and write it to a label on my form, so the user has some way of knowing that an error occurred and why it occurred. I considered using `Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd`, but it will always return `null`. I believe this is because the `Process` itself is cmd, not setup.exe (where the error actually occurs).

I've read that it's possible to get the last error code in cmd using `echo %errorlabel%`, and that does work when I run it manually, so I tried implementing it in my code:

```
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo %errorlevel%");
            string s = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            p.WaitForExit();
```

I was hoping that `s` would be set to the output of the `echo %errorlevel%` input, but it is just set to `null`.

How can I get the error code of SQL Server setup, through my cmd `Process`?

Just as a side note, I've considered running setup.exe as the `Process`, but it requires elevation, which means enabling `UseShellExecute`, which in turn means disabling `RedirectStandardError`, which would prevent me getting the error code anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is all not necessary, the exit code of the "executable" invoked with `cmd.exe /c` will be the exit code of `cmd.exe` itself.

You can try this on the command line as well:

```
c:\> cmd.exe /c app.exe make-it-fail
c:\> echo %errorlevel%
```

The second line will print the exit code of "app.exe make-it-fail".

So, just read the value of the `Process.ExitCode` property, after `Process.WaitForExit()`.

What particular values `setup.exe` (of SQL Server) sets in case it fails, I don't know. Should be something different than `0` though (by convention).